# Vue 2.0 bootstrap 3 datepicker component

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, datepicker, vue.js, vue-component

Where can I find a decent vue 2.0 bootstrap 3 datepicker component. I have tried almost everything out there. Most of the datepickers are vue 1.0 compatible.

I'm looking for something simple, to import in my child component, apply v-model on it and ready to go.

Comment: google.com is the way to find it

Comment: Take a look at: http://gambardella.info/2016/09/05/guide-how-to-use-vue-js-with-jquery-plugins/

Answer (score 1):

Check my github project https://github.com/wxsms/uiv (Bootstrap 3 components implemented by Vue 2.)

Install:

```
npm install uiv --save
```

A simple code example:

```
<template>
  <date-picker v-model="date"/>
</template>
<script>
  import {DatePicker} from 'uiv'
  export default {
    components: {DatePicker},
    data () {
      return {
        date: null
      }
    }
  }
</script>
<!-- date-picker-example.vue -->
```

This will create an inline datepicker for you. for more usages (e.g. with form and dropdown) you can checkout the document page: https://uiv.wxsm.space/date-picker

Comment: you need to disclaim clearly if you are linking to your own project/blog

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to [vue-flatpickr](https://github.com/jrainlau/vue-flatpickr). it isn't bootstrap datepicker but it's a really good alternative without jquery dependency.

Answer (score 0):

The link in previous comment is dead.
Use [this vue component](https://github.com/ankurk91/vue-flatpickr-component) instead.

```
npm install vue-flatpickr-component --save
```

It is dead simple to use.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <flat-pickr v-model="date"></flat-pickr>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import flatPickr from 'vue-flatpickr-component';
  import 'flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.css';

  export default {    
    data () {
      return {
        date: null,       
      }
    },
    components: {
      flatPickr
    }
  }
</script>
```